# Что такое data-toggle="modal" и для чего применяется?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Нигде не могу найти внятного ответа

Answer (score 8):

Это [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) атрибуты. Используются для добавления дополнительной информации к DOM-элементу. Из статьи по ссылке:

### Синтаксис HTML

Синтаксис прост — любой атрибут, чьё имя начинается с `data-`, является `data-*` атрибутом. Предположим у нас имеется статья и мы хотим сохранить дополнительную информацию без визуального представления. Для этого можно использовать `data`-атрибуты:

```
<article
  id="electriccars"
  data-columns="3"
  data-index-number="12314"
  data-parent="cars">
...
</article>
```

### Доступ в JavaScript

Чтение `data`-атрибутов в JavaScript осуществляется также просто. Для этого можно использовать метод [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) с параметром, равным полному имени атрибута. Но есть и более простой способ, используя объект [`.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Чтобы получить `data`-атрибут можно взять свойство объекта `dataset` с именем, равным части имени атрибута после `data-` (обратите внимание, что дефисы в имени преобразуются в camelCase).

```
let article = document.getElementById('electriccars');

article.dataset.columns // "3"
article.dataset.indexNumber // "12314"
article.dataset.parent // "cars"
```

Каждое свойство является строкой и может быть прочитано и записано. В приведённом выше примере выполнение кода `article.dataset.columns = 5` приведёт к тому, что новое значение атрибута станет равным `"5"`.