# Как получить значение data атрибута?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, вёрстка

При собитии *change* селекта, я в переменную *location* получаю *value* той option, которая выбрана. Но как получить значение *data* атрибута выбранной опции? Например, как мне получить значение атрибута *data-lat* ?

```
<select class="select">
    <option class="" value="Лондон" data-lat="50.451000" data-lng="30.523689">Лондон</option>
    <option class="" value="Вашингтон" data-lat="75.851000" data-lng="12.45500">Вашингтон</option>
    <option class="" value="Нью-Йорк" data-lat="85.451080" data-lng="75.458500">Нью-Йорк</option>
</select>

$('.select').on('change', function () {
    var location = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое data-toggle="modal" и для чего применяется?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771210/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-data-toggle-modal-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

var attr = $(this).getAttribute('data-lat')

Comment: я пробовал так делать, но возвращается undefined

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуй

Comment: так тоже undefined получается

Comment: Обновил ещё раз попробуй

Comment: возвращает ошибку: getAttribute is not a function

Comment: я нашел, что document.getElementsByTagName("option") возвращает коллекцию элементов, где нет метода getAttribute. Сперва необходимо получить какую-то конкретную ноду и уже потом работать с атрибутами

Answer (score 4):

вот так получилось вывести:

```
$('.select').change(function() {
    var selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    console.log(selectedOption.getAttribute("data-lat"));
});
```

Comment: Красавчик, хорошо получилось!

Answer (score 3):

А в JQ нужно всего лишь `$('.elem').data('lat');`.. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

> Так я jQuery и использовал, и такой способ тоже пробовал, он возвращает undefined

Хм.. Есть такое..

А как такой вариант?

```js
$('.select').bind('change',function(){
  var valThis = $(this).val().split(','),
      lat = valThis[0],
      lng = valThis[1];
      
  $('.lat').text('lat: '+lat);
  $('.lng').text('lng: '+lng);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="select">
    <option class="" value="50.451000,30.523689">Лондон</option>
    <option class="" value="75.851000,12.45500">Вашингтон</option>
    <option class="" value="85.451080,75.458500">Нью-Йорк</option>
</select>

<div>
  <span class="lat">lat: </span>
  <br>
  <span class="lng">lng: </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Так я jQuery и использовал, и такой способ тоже пробовал, он возвращает undefined

Comment: @SergeyKonovalenko, обновил

Comment: можно и такой способ использовать